# Chrome скроллит при обновлении страницы

Tags: google-chrome

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что у хрома за настройка такая и как ее отключить? При открытии сайта, он открывается на том месте, где был закрыт. И так с любым сайтом. В других браузерах сайты открываются как обычно сначала

Comment: Так и должно быть. Это же хорошо. Вроде в других браузерах так же.

Comment: просто клиент хочет чтоб его сайт открывался сверху всегда...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте запустить этот код когда страница загрузится.

```
window.scrollTo(0);
```

Если же нужно вделать это на всех сайтах, а не только на вашем - воспользуйтесь расширением [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) чтоб добавить кастомные скрипты на сайт.

Comment: в консоли выдало Uncaught TypeError: window.scrollTo is not a function

Comment: когда именно вы запускали? После загрузки страницы или когда?
У меня работает, странно...

Comment: я на обум сразу в начале страницы это вставил)). Надо было на onload вешать или просто в конец страницы добавить. В принципе я понял что это хром так открывает сайты, которые уже были открыты ранее. Объясню заказчику, если все-равно скажет чтоб сайт всегда открывался сначала, тогда уже воспользуюсь вашей рекомендацией. Спасибо!

Comment: кстати, у вас тоже хром открывает на том же месте сайт, на котором был закрыт?

Answer (score 0):

В начало можно просколлить так:

```
window.scrollTo({ top: 0 })
```